# Webpack - sass-loader can't figure out how includePaths work

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader

I am a bit stuck, and right now I am at the verge of a breakdown. Someone, PLEASE enlighten me what is happening here. I am playing around with this for like 4 hours now, and can't seem to find out why this is happening!

**TL/DR: Why is it, that `webpack` does not find my `config.scss` file based on the second `includePath` provided, but can resolve it based on the first? Yet it will resolve the `test.scss` file in any case?**

I have the following webpack configuration:

```
 //webpack.config.js
 ... unrelated code ...
 module.exports = merge(common, {
     ... unrelated code ...
     modules: {
         rules: [
             {
                 test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
                 exclude: /\.module.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
                 loader: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            implementation: require('sass'),
                            sassOptions: {
                                importer: globImporter(),
                                includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/'), path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/config/')]
                            }
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }
         ]
    },
    ... unrelated code ...
});
```

This loader will load the `test.js` file, which in my test example does nothing more, then loading a simple `scss` file, the `test.scss`. Here's how that file looks like:

```
// src/entry/test.scss
@use 'config' as *;
@use 'dummy' as *;

@debug $test;
```

The `dummy.scss` file contains some css code for test, but no variables. It looks like this:

```
// src/main/dummy.scss
body {
  font-size: 50rem;
}
```

The `config.scss` file looks like this:

```
// src/main/config/config.scss
$test: "TEST VALUE";
```

Here's the complete directory tree, relevant from the perspective of the scss

```
src/
   main/
       config/
           config.scss
       dummy.scss
   entry/
       test.scss
```

My expected output is that when I run webpack, a `test.css` file should be created in a folder, which should contain the only thing found in the `dummy.scss` and webpack should output my debug information on the screen.

Now if I try to run webpack like this, I get an error, that the `$test` variable is not defined, and no `css` file is created. But strangely, if I change the `test.scss` files first `@use` command to: `@use 'config/config.scss' as *` everything runs flawlesly: the `.css` file is created with the expected result, and the `@debug` command outputs the expected string on the screen.

Why is it, that `webpack` does not find my `config.scss` file based on the second `includePath` provided, but can resolve it based on the first?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but was unable to use includePaths until your question led me to set my value to a directory or two above where the actual .scss files live, and that did the trick.
Not sure why that is. It's a bit frustrating, and requires my imports to be a bit more lengthy.

Comment: @Orion if I am not mistaken, webpack imports scss files relative to the base scss file imported, which is indeed a bit frustrating. But you can use this plugin: `resolve-url-loader` which will help you to have relative imports to the actual file that is being processed. https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader